# Copy span text to input field automatically when page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to copy text content of span and automatically paste to input field when page load.
Whenever I used the `getElementByClassName` code are not working but when I used `getElementById` code are working perfectly.

Please assists, thank you so much.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('showTag').value = document.getElementByClassName('addTag')[0].textContent;
});
```

```html
<p class="addTag">
  Copy this to input field
</p>

<input name="showTag" type="text" id="showTag" />
```

Comment: Edited to remove `php` and `css` tags because they are unrelated

Comment: I edited your question to a snippet, and now you can see the exception that you should be able to see in your browser console.

Comment: typo error it is getElement s ByClassName,   element is plural

Comment: @MisterJojo ahaha you made it, Thank bro.

Comment: use F12 this kind of error make info in console

Answer (score 0):

You got it right, just an typo: `getElementByClassName`

should be: `getElementsByClassName`.

> document.getElementsByClassName('addTag')[0].textContent;

Though, since you know  and always expect it's always the first element, you might as well write like so:

> document.querySelector('addTag').textContent;

```
<p class="addTag">
  Copy this to input field
</p>

<input name="showTag" type="text" id="showTag" />

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  document.getElementById('showTag').value = document.getElementsByClassName('addTag')[0].textContent;
  // or 
  document.getElementById('showTag').value = document.querySelector('.addTag').textContent;

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Hakik Thank you for your answer, but I already found the problem, I forgot to put an "s" getElementByClassName it sould be getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's written in the start of the answer.

Comment: Oh! I see now that I accidently switched order of them, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

```
 window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName('addTag')[0].innerHTML;
 var y = document.getElementById('showTag');
 y.value=x;
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dbwpox38/

Comment: Someone added a comment on this reply saying "questions about typos don't deserve a response and they get deleted on SO" then they down voted my answer. Can any senior confirm that this is the case? If so I’ll have to stop answering everything just in case someone makes a typo and I miss it...